# Unicode error handling with Python 3's readlines()

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, encoding

I keep getting this error while reading a text file. Is it possible to handle/ignore it and proceed?

> UnicodeEncodeError: ‘charmap’ codec can’t decode byte 0x81 in position
>   7827: character maps to undefined.

Comment: This varies a _lot_ based on details. Python 2? Python 3? Are you trying to decode strings you already read? How? Etc.

Comment: Python 3. I'm using readlines()

Comment: Okay -- updated the question to specify Python 3. Unicode is one of the places where there are very big differences between 2 and 3; please be sure to specify version explicitly in the future.

Comment: For a more general case, it is probably worth looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199571/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-invalid

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Python 3, pass an appropriate `errors=` value (such as `errors=ignore` or `errors=replace`) on creating your file object (presuming it to be a subclass of `io.TextIOWrapper` -- and if it isn't, consider wrapping it in one!); also, consider passing a more likely encoding than `charmap` (when you aren't sure, `utf-8` is always a good place to start).

For instance:

```
f = open('misc-notes.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

---

In Python 2, the `read()` operation simply returns bytes; the trick, then, is decoding them to get them into a string (if you do, in fact, want characters as opposed to bytes). If you don't have a better guess for their real encoding:

```
your_string.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
```

...to replace unhandled characters, or

```
your_string.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

to simply ignore them.

That said, finding and using their *real* encoding (rather than guessing `utf-8`) would be preferred.

Comment: Minor nitpick: in Python 2, the trick is *decoding* them, not encoding. But you know that, because you're calling the `decode` method.

Comment: @ThomasK Oops. Shortened the verbiage -- fewer things to get wrong. Thanks for the proofread. :)

Comment: by passing encoding and errors parameters, it seems to be working.

Comment: Question: is there a way to check which encoding the file has been generated with?

Comment: @Bob sure -- just check `fileobj.encoding` (and `fileobj.errors` for the error-handling mode); should work as long as `fileobj` is a `TextIOWrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file with a codecs to make sure that the file gets interpreted as UTF8.

```
import codecs
fd = codecs.open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8')
data = fd.read()
```

Answer (score -5):

Yeah..you could wrap it in a

```
try:
    ....
except UnicodeEncodeError: 
    pass
```

Comment: yes, but that doesn't help much in terms of explaining how to proceed with reading the rest of the file.