# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte error in python while reading a csv file

Tags: python, byte-order-mark

```
StopWords = pd.read_csv('stopwords.csv',encoding='UTF-8', quotechar='|',names=['StopWords'])
```

I am trying to read a CSV file that contains Persian language text, and this is the error I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

Comment: Open the text file in a hex editor (HxD is a good one on Windows) and update your question with the first line of text and the associated bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the binary content of the file it is difficult to guess the actual encoding but UTF-8, with or without a BOM (Byte order Marker) cannot start with an 0xFF.

If it starts with an 0xFF, then that would suggest that it is probably in Little Endian UTF-16 to UTF-32 which are the only Unicode serialisations that have a byte order marker starting with 0xFF.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark gives some explanation.

It is also possible that it is a Persian specific character set. National character sets should be avoided if a Unicode option is available, for the generation of your source CSV files.

Comment: Thank you. In my case the correct encoding was UTF-16, base on the BOM Wikipedia article you pasted.

Comment: Thanks Fabio - `utf-16` solved my issue.