# UTF8 decoding error, total beginner so im having a hard time understanding other responses to similar issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, reddit, praw

I'm trying to learn Python. I'm using a script from GitHub and trying to understand how it works. However, I get a UTF-8 decoding error when running it. Here is the log:

```
% python3 ticker_counts.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/filipalvgren/Desktop/Reddit-Stock-Trends/back/ticker_counts.py", line 102, in <module>
    ticket.get_data()
  File "/Users/filipalvgren/Desktop/Reddit-Stock-Trends/back/ticker_counts.py", line 49, in get_data
    reddit = praw.Reddit('ClientSecrets')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.config = Config(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/config.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._load_config(config_interpolation)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/config.py", line 60, in _load_config
    config.read(locations)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 1017, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
filipalvgren@Filips-MBP-2 back %
```

From what I can understand, the error is in the `codecs.py` file, but I can't seem to find anything that helps me in line 322. Sorry if this a beginner question, but any help on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `praw.ini` file is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte error in python while reading a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199571/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-invalid)