# Python - Read a file which contains bytes and strings

Tags: python, file, encoding, byte

I work on a program in python which analyze files and keep only what I want in these files.
I have an error when I open some files. These files contains string and bytes like that :

```
file.py:
if byte == "0xFD":
    for byte in bytes.split["0xFD"]:
...
```

When I open that type of files, the strings present between quotes are interpreted as bytes and that makes the program crashed :
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 59752: character maps to <undefined>`. Same error with 'utf-8'.

So my question is: how can I read that line without interpreted the byte (I want to keep the line like that)?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `rb` in your `open` function, it will read the bytes as UTF-8.

```
file = open("insertfilenamehere.txt", "rb")
txt = file.read()
```

Comment: That makes this error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I want :
`with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='replace') as file:`

I found some help on this post : [Unicode error handling with Python 3's readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487563/unicode-error-handling-with-python-3s-readlines)