# How to fix Python pip install openai error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm trying to install OpenAI with Python 3.11, Windows OS, pip fully upgraded, and I got this error.

Here is the full error message:

```
Collecting openai
  Using cached openai-0.26.0.tar.gz (54 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lr3fjsgg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lr3fjsgg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lr3fjsgg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 485, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vocal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lr3fjsgg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1031: illegal multibyte sequence
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have no idea how to solve this error. Can anybody give me a hint?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1031: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Because of that message, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487563/unicode-error-handling-with-python-3s-readlines) solution and it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem recently on a fresh Linux VM, but the solution was actually quite simple. I added the pip version to the install command, e.g. **`pip3.10 install openai`** and everything worked as intended.

This may not be the same issue for your Windows environment, but [here is the full write up I posted](https://www.ericjstauffer.com/blog/python-error-when-installing-openai-subprocess-exited-with-error) since I couldn't find any helpful information at the time.

Comment: Just for the note, I had the same issue on Google colab and running
`%pip install --upgrade pip
%pip install openai` worked.

Answer (score 7):

I working in Google Colab and I have the same issue. I fixed it by doing the same thing.

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install openai
```

Comment: As of March 9, 2023, the above solution works in Colab. Running `!pip install --upgrade pip` upgrades `pip-22.0.4` to `pip-23.0.1`, the version required for openai to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue with 3.12.0 version of python.
I have unistall same and install 3.11.0

Comment: and? did that resolve the problem?