# How to fix pip install openai error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip, openai-api

I installed the openai package, but there was an error. I have no idea about this error. The Python version is 3.11.1, and the pip version is 22.3.1.

```
Collecting openai
  Using cached openai-0.26.0.tar.gz (54 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process          main()
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b5meduhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b5meduhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b5meduhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 485, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chase\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b5meduhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1031: illegal multibyte sequence
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I checked the pip and python versions. There seems to be no problem with the version.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067851/how-to-fix-python-pip-install-openai-error-subprocess-exited-with-error/

Comment: thanks! I didn't know it was a duplicate..