# Intermittent failure when pip install openai

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-api

I am using Colab and running `pip install openai`

The process seem to be completed with the following message.  But the module is not installed.  Cannot `import openai`

This problem is intermittent.  Sometime it works.  I have tried the suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067851/how-to-fix-python-pip-install-openai-error-subprocess-exited-with-error) but cannot reliably solve it.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting openapi
  Downloading openapi-1.1.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting inflection>=0.3.1 (from openapi)
  Downloading inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from openapi) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6.0->openapi) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6.0->openapi) (0.19.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: openapi
  Building wheel for openapi (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for openapi: filename=openapi-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=12693 sha256=558abb2a15b29632551fdf75028bd13ae5ac60ff744dbd1009f7471e31d769a0
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/34/8f/d2/7949d6db12c5a156156b149b5ac8a65866f6cc7e264a1ef179
Successfully built openapi
Installing collected packages: inflection, openapi
Successfully installed inflection-0.5.1 openapi-1.1.0
```

Comment: You've got to install these two pip packages: **tiktoken**, **cohere**